# How do I convert list of positive integers to negative integers in python?

Tags: python-2.7

Okay so to preface I am trying to write an encryption program that takes a string input, uses the ord() function for convert each character into an integer and then shift it using a pseudorandomly generated sequence of numbers. It is essentially a vigenere cipher program and I've pretty much got it down pat. I am only having trouble with the decryption function, as I do not know how to substract the key from the encrypted message so that I can decrypt it.

```
def input1():
    mes = raw_input('> ').upper()
    shiftl = []
    while len(mes) > len(shiftl):
        shiftl.append(random.randint(1,26))
    return mes, shiftl

def encrypt(x,y):
    h = []
    for item in x:
        h.append(ord(item) - 65)
    e = [sum(i) for i in zip(h,y)]
    return e

def decrypt(e, y):
    u = [sum(i) for i in zip(e,-(y))]
    d = []
    for item in u:
        d.append(chr(item + 65))
    return d
```

This is the line I need help with.

```
u = [sum(i) for i in zip(e,-(y))]
```

I tried to simply put a - in front of the list but unary operators do not work on lists. So what is the best way for me to go about subtracting this list from the encrypted message?

Comment: You can get a negative number by subtracting the positive number from zero. `-3 == 0 - 3`

Answer (score 2):

If you have a list and you would like to change the contents use a list comprehension with a slice assignment:

```
a = [1, 3, 5]
a[:] = [-1*x for x in a]
print a
```

The output of this would be:

```
[-1, -3, -5]
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely I did not get what exactly you are looking for, but for the other case:

```
def negList(list):
    for(n in list):
        n = -n
    return list

list = negList(list)
```

Sorry, in case I got you wrong.

Comment: this is definitely what I want but it isn't working as intended. As you wrote it, it returns the list I input with no changes. I defined n = -n as a separate function and used .append in a for loop to create a list but I get a list full of 'None'